# having problems using typed.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typed.js

i recently tried to use typed.js but it does not work the html page code is listed below, if there are any alternatives or any other way to get a similar effect then please share or help me to fix this issue

code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/dist/typed.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        var heading = $(".typed");
        if(heading.length){
            heading.typed({
                strings: ["Startups", "Business", "Agencies"],
                // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
                stringsElement: null,
                typeSpeed: 100,
                startDelay: 500,
                backSpeed: 100,
                backDelay: 500,
                loop: true,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                attr: null,
                contentType: 'html',
                callback: function() {},
                preStringTyped: function() {},
                onStringTyped: function() {},
                resetCallback: function() {}
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>We are <span class="typed"></span> </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code: The URL from where you trying to import typed.js is broken and you initialize typed in a wrong way. Here's a working example:

```js
 var heading = $(".typed");
        if(heading.length){
 var typed1 = new Typed('.typed', {        
                strings: ["Startups", "Business", "Agencies"],
                // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
                stringsElement: null,
                typeSpeed: 100,
                startDelay: 500,
                backSpeed: 100,
                backDelay: 500,
                loop: true,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                attr: null,
                contentType: 'html',
                callback: function() {},
                preStringTyped: function() {},
                onStringTyped: function() {},
                resetCallback: function() {}
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
<h2>We are <span class="typed"></span> </h2>
```